# Immutable variables in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm learning OCaml, and I'm a bit confused with the immutability of variables. According to the book I'm reading, variables are immutable. So far so good, but why on Earth can I do this:

```
let foo = 42
let foo = 4242
```

What am I missing??

Comment: you aren't changing the value of the previous one, merely making a new foo which is name shadowing the previous one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way to explain is with an example. Consider this code (executed in the OCaml REPL):

```
# let foo = 42;;
val foo : int = 42

# let return_foo () = foo;;
val return_foo : unit -> int = <fun>

# let foo = 24;;
val foo : int = 24

# return_foo ();;
- : int = 42
```

The above code does the following:

1. Binds `42` to the name `foo`.
2. Creates a function `return_foo ()` that returns the value bound to `foo`.
3. Binds `24` to the name `foo` (which hides the previous binding of `foo`).
4. Calls the `return_foo ()` function, which returns `42`.

Compare this with the behaviour of a mutable value (created using `ref` in OCaml):

```
# let foo = ref 42;;
val foo : int ref = {contents = 42}

# let return_foo () = !foo;;
val return_foo : unit -> int = <fun>

# foo := 24;;
- : unit = ()

# return_foo ();;
- : int = 24
```

which:

1. Creates a mutable reference containing `42` and binds it to the name `foo`.
2. Creates a function `return_foo ()` that returns the value stored in the reference bound to `foo`.
3. Stores `24` in the reference bound to `foo`.
4. Calls the `return_foo ()` function, which returns `24`.

Answer (score 4):

The name `foo` is first bound to an immutable value `42` and later it is rebound to another immutable value `4242`. You can even bind the same name to variables of different types. In OCaml we are talking not about mutability of a variable, but about a mutability of a value. For example, if you bind `foo` to an array of values, this would be the same name, but bound to a mutable data, so that the value of a variable can change in time. Finally, each new binding just hides the previous one, so the original foo is still bound to `42`, but it is invisible and will garbage collected.

Maybe a little example will clarify the idea:

```
let example () = 
  let foo = 42     in (* 1 *)
  let foo = 4242   in (* 2 *)
  let foo = [|42|] in (* 3 *)
  foo.(0) <- 56       (* 4 *)
```

It might be easier to have the following mental model:

```
                  (*1*)  +--------+
                  +----> |   42   |
+------------+    |      +--------+
|            +----+
|    foo     +----+      +--------+
|            |    +----> |  4242  |
+---------+--+    (*2*)  +--------+
          |
          |       (*3*)  +--------+
          +------------> |[| 42 |]|
                  (*4*)  +--------+
```

On lines `1` and `2` we just bind a variable `foo` to two different values. On line `3` we bind it to an array that contains one element. On line `4`, we change the value, and foo is still bound to the same value, but the value contains different datum.

I hope I didn't confuse you even more ;)

Answer (score 3):

The usual form of `let` is the `let ... in` expression, where you define a variable binding, which only exists in the inside of the body of the `let`. The body of the `let` is a new scope.

```
let x = 42 in (* body here *)
```

Here the "body" of the `let` is a new scope that is different from the one outside, with all the variables from the outside with an additional local variable `x` that is only defined in the body of this `let`.

Now you are talking about `let`s at the top level of the file. These look a little different syntactically (there is no `in`), but really they are the same, with the "body" being the rest of the file. So here you can think of the rest of the file after the `let` as a new scope, with `x` being a local variable of this scope. So your code is equivalent to this:

```
let foo = 42 in (
  let foo = 4242 in (
    (* rest of file *)
  )
)
```

Here your inner `let` binds a local variable that has the same name as a variable that already exists in the outer scope. That doesn't matter. You are binding a new variable in an inner scope. If it happens to have the same name as a variable in an outer scope, then code in the inner scope referencing that name will refer to the innermost binding. The two variables, however, are completely independent.

In a C-like language, it would be something like this:

```
{
    const int foo = 42;
    {
        const int foo = 4242;
        // rest of code here
    }
}
```

See? There is no assignment to any variables here.