# Can I reuse variable name in Scala and "obliterate" the previous name?

Tags: scala

I'm writing a long-ish computation in Scala, and I want to organize my code in the following way:

```
val x = 2 * 2
val x = x + 3
val x = x ** 5

// Result is x = 45
```

I don't care about referencing the old values of `x` after this; I'm only interested in the last value.  The code above thinks I'm writing recursive expressions on `x`.  How can I write this?

(Similar code (`x = x + 3`) would work in python and [in OCaml too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641464/immutable-variables-in-ocaml), and it makes some things like complex math expressions really simple.)

Comment: Not idiomatic Scala, but you could just make `x` a `var` and modify its value as you wish. Proper FP code avoids mutable variables.

Comment: At least read the basic documentation of the language before asking: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html - Anyways according to mathematics variables do not change.

Comment: Why not just use different variable names? If you want to hide them, use a block, like joel's answer does. And in this example of yours, at least, you can turn all of that into a single term (`val x = math.pow(5, 2 * 2 + 3)`)

Comment: @PShved so you want the same variable to hold different values but you do not want to change a variable? You can find `vars` in the first section of the **tour** whose title is [**basics**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/basics.html).

Comment: Anyways, it seems you would be interested in the new changing dsl if you are in `2.13+`, or in using the **Id** monad if you are in `2.12-`, see this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/VAtBOjRFSO6lOTZdVf0Ejw/4

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't think you're being fair. Besides, this is more than just about `var`s

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, the examples you linked look interesting, albeit a bit heavyweight for the purpose.  Huge kudos.

Comment: Bad audit item :-/ not sure why this was closed in the first place. "How can I do this" is the quintessential question form on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rust approach might be something like @jwvh suggests*, but in its own block

```
val x = {
  var y = 2 * 2
  y = y + 3
  y = y * 5
  y
}
```

Keeps the mutability contained. Dunno how idiomatic this would be

*though in rust you can `let x = ...` more than once

Comment: Yep, Python, Rust, and this is also valid OCaml: `let x = 2 in
let x = x + 3 in
let x = x * x in
x ;;`

Comment: Well, since ppl downvoted and have decided to close my question, and I'm not getting any more answers to it, congratulations joel your answer wins!  It's a very neat way to constrain the immutability too.

Comment: @PShved well in any case the thing is there couldn't be any other answer. In **Scala** you either use `vars` or invent new names _(which is exactly what you do not want to do)_ or use new scopes to reuse the same name _(that is what `pipe` and `Id.map` did)_